# expecting to save Double in the db but mongo decide to save it as Int64 (big number)

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

im using unit test to check what type will be inserted to the db, my code is simple:

```
"insert big double to mongo" in {
  val doc: MyDocument = generateMyDocument()
  val newdoc = doc.copy(myDoubleField = 2394735300.0)
  dao.insertOne(newdoc, action).futureValue
}
```

this will insert int64 for the field myDoubleField which supposed to be Double..

if I change the number to be 24,735,300 it get saved as int32..

if I change the number to  2,735,300 it get saved as Double!

this is very weird to me I don't understand.

my insertOne method looks like:

```
  def insertOne(doc: Doc, action: EventAction): Future[Doc] = {
    doc.createdAt = Some(InstantNow)
    doc.updatedAt = doc.createdAt
    (for {
      insertedDoc <- collection.insert.one(doc)
        .map({
        case DefaultWriteResult(true, 1, _, _, _, _) => doc
        case dwr => throw new RuntimeException(s"$LogName was not inserted, something went wrong: $dwr")
      })
      _ <- eventsCollection.insert.one(EventDocument(action, DataOperation.Create, dataType, None, doc._id, doc.metadata, None, None, None))
    } yield insertedDoc)
      .recover({
        case WriteResult.Code(DuplicateCode) => throw DuplicateKeyException(doc.uniqueIndexToString)
      })
  }
```

please, how do I ensure I save it as Double, thanks!

Comment: You can cast it explicitly as Double.

Comment: @SaraM. how do I do that?

Comment: val newdoc = doc.copy(myDoubleField = 2394735300.0.asInstanceOf[Double])

Comment: `2394735300d` should do it

Comment: @SaraM. that dosent work, still saved as int64

Comment: @Dima that dosent work, still saved as int64 unfortunately

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula no databricks at this point, we have another area we use it but not here, why?

Comment: the MongoDB server will save values using the BSON types indicated by the driver. what is the driver that you are using ?

Comment: @SaraM. im using reactivemongo

Comment: Try this val myDoubleField = BSONDouble(2394735300.0D)

Comment: There are a lot of important missing details. How are you checking the type in Mongo (provide code/commands/ui screenshots) ? What is MyDocument ? What is generateMyDocument ?